# Universal Windows Phone 8.1 App crashes when scrolling too fast in WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to load html content from a string using WebView.NavigateToString.The page loads fine but when I scroll before all content is loaded the app crashes. The debugger in Visual Studio 2013 doesn't detect the crash instead it says the app exited normally. The memory usage of the app is also low around 50mb.

This is the code I have used to navigate to the page with the WebViewer.

**MainPage.cs**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }


    private void article1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(webviewpage),"<!doctype html><html><head><style>img {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%; height: auto} li { font-size: 2em; } ul { font-size: 25px; } iframe { width: 950; height: 720; display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto} blockquote { font-size: 3em; font-style:italic; }</style></head><body><p><b>[Vídeo] Os melhores jogos gratuitos para Windows Phone #3</b></p><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Hoje temos mais uma vez uma dica de 5 games gratuitos para Windows Phone. Se o seu jogo favorito não aparecer nesta seleção, confira os <a href=\"http://www.wpmania.com.br/2014/06/26/video-5-jogos-gratuitos-estilo-plataforma-01/\" target=\"_blank\">outros vídeos</a> pois ele pode estar lá e, caso não esteja, deixe o nome dele nos comentários para que o nosso parceiro Marcos possa fazer o vídeo com a dica para os demais leitores!</p><p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><strong>Sem mais delongas, confira o vídeo abaixo: </strong></p><p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/rDiL8Z_nz0k\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></p></body></html>");            
    }
```

**webviewpage.cs**

```
public webviewpage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.NavigateToString(e.Parameter.ToString());
    }
```

**webviewpage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.webviewpage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <WebView Name="browser"></WebView>
</Grid>
```

The complete solution can be downloaded here: http://speedy.sh/aedfb/App2.rar .The app crashes less often when using the emulator compared to a real device (Lumia 520 in my case). Pick an article an article and scroll down as fast as you can and the app will crash.

My question is what causes the app to crash or does anybody know a way how I can debug the crash? Even if the html does not contain images or iframes it still crashes.

Comment: I am experiencing the same bug. No exceptions raise. And no error reports when uplodated to the store (as a beta app).

Comment: I made a video on how to make the app crash http://youtu.be/-hUfrD8ke7o

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a bug in Windows Phone 8.1, reported working as of version 8.10.14176.xx.

For complete discussion, please refer to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/854abfa2-5312-4583-92d9-26430c7f5d9c/universal-app-webview-crashing-when-scrolling-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop#2344d0b6-f32c-4ff7-b0a5-b41d04c26e2c